# Chi-Square Test

Tags: statistics, chi-squared

I have a question regarding the chi-square test. Why is the chi-square goodness of fit test, a chi-square independence test, or a chi-square homogeneity test is always right-tailed?

Comment: You'd expect at least *some* kind of tail and $X^2$ is nonnegatively valued, right? Perhaps I misunderstand the question.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant.